# web scraping (script nonce) using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[this is the image which shows the extra amount of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwoYi.png)how can i extract the code from script tag from a specific nonce,I tried many ways but can fetch extragavant data,I cannot extract only the exact limit of data.

`import requests, bs4
    import json
    # getting HTML from the Google Play web page
    url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en"
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup.prettify())
    reviews = soup.find_all('script')`

Comment: this is the sample url:-"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en"

Comment: share your code instead of just a screenshot

Comment: done @PeterPrescott

Comment: Thanks dear Raunak for sharing the code - this is very helpful!

Comment: your most welcome @zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `soup.find()` instead of `soup.find_all()`.

If the specific *nonce* you are interested in is `s6eT15ofB4Da+TMeu645CA`, then just add this to the bottom of the code you already have:

```
soup.find(nonce="s6eT15ofB4Da+TMeu645CA")
```

Comment: Thanks dear Peter for this explanation - thanks for the answer!